# Custom UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I was curious about how people make their own search interface, I really do not like the standard and decided to write my own. I do not know how to write my own, so I ask to prompt, where you can see all that I know - that's what is needed to create your own `UIView`.

An example of what I want to do[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. But it looks like you want a standard UISearchBar.

Answer (score 1):

I once made something similar, if you use swift ,study this code, it will help you, if this is not helpful explain further please.

[image]

```
func addNavigationBar()
{
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let centerView = UIView(frame:  CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30))

    let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")

    var btnMiddle = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,5,80,20))
    btnMiddle.setBackgroundImage(logo, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnMiddle.addTarget(self, action: "goBackHome", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    centerView.addSubview(btnMiddle)

    self.navigationItem.titleView = centerView

        var buttonDimension = CGFloat(25)

        let rightView = UIView(frame:  CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30))
        let leftView = UIView(frame:  CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30))

        let btnr1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(30,0,buttonDimension,buttonDimension))
        btnr1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "_barSearch.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btnr1.addTarget(self, action: "search", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        rightView.addSubview(btnr1)

        let btnr2 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(80,0,buttonDimension,buttonDimension))
        btnr2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "_barSettinges.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btnr2.addTarget(self, action: "settinges", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        rightView.addSubview(btnr2)

        let btnl3 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,buttonDimension,buttonDimension))
        btnl3.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "_barMenu.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btnl3.addTarget(self, action: "menu", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        leftView.addSubview(btnl3)

        let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightView)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn

        let leftBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftView)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBtn

}
```

Comment: i dont know swift i use obj-c but great thanx, can you translate this is obj-c?